# OpenGIS Tile data server for Cesium?

Tags: open-source-gis, cesium, opengis

I'm investigating my options for local hosting test GIS data for use with Cesium front ends.  I have seen this project: [Cesium Terrain Server](https://github.com/geo-data/cesium-terrain-server) but it seems quite old.

I thought I read somewhere that Cesium can use [OpenGIS Web Map Tile Service](https://www.ogc.org/standards/wmts#downloads) servers.

Can Cesium front ends (CesiumJS, Unreal Plugin etc) be used with servers that implement the OpenGIS Web Map Tile Service standards?

Answer (score 0):

Yes.
Please have look at these.

https://cesium.com/learn/cesiumjs/ref-doc/WebMapServiceImageryProvider.html
https://cesium.com/learn/cesiumjs/ref-doc/WebMercatorTilingScheme.html